# Where are Grails 2.4.2 installed plugin files?

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I installed Spring Security Core plugin for my Grails project and it works just fine. The problem is that I can't locate the actual plugin files. I can't find any of my projects inside `.grails/2.4.2/projects` where according to my understanding Grails is suppose to store all the plugins. The directors exists but there are no projects in this folder.If I want to edit `grails.plugin.springsecurity.LoginController` where do I go to find this controller? I am on `OS X 10.9.3`

Comment: Check your BuildConfig.groovy. By default there should be line like: grails.project.work.dir = "target/work" where your project and plugin data will be stored

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the plugins are in `.grails/<version>/<project>/plugins`. You can change it by setting `grails.project.plugins.dir` (setting it to 'plugins' will create a plugins folder in your project source directory) in `BuildConfig.groovy`.

then copy the `LoginController` to your own source tree (to the same location) to override and edit the plugin version.

Comment: Thanks, I did set grails.project.plugins.dir = "plugins" which created a plugins folder in my project source. But this folder doesn't contain the source files of the plugin. I had to import the same folder as a Grails project separately and now I able to edit the plugin source files. I am using the Groovy/Grails Tool suit.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone else runs into this.

In 2.4.4 you would put the theme into

```
/<project>/target/work/plugins/jquery-ui-<version>/web-app/jquery-ui/themes/<themename>/
```